# Django Rest Framework. Подскажите какую-нибудь библиотеку для умного поиска

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, filter, django-filter

Хочу сделать умный фильтр по кверисету по одному полю, способный найти объекты, даже если пользователем была допущена ошибка или если пользователь забыл переключить раскладку клавиатуры, как это происходит в поисковиках.

Пока что накидал такой метод в фильтрах

```
from django.contrib.postgres.search import SearchQuery, SearchVector
from django_filters import rest_framework as filters


class AddressFilter(filters.FilterSet):
    name = filters.CharFilter(method='filter_name_smart')

    class Meta:
        model = Address
        fields = ['name']

    def filter_name_smart(self, queryset, name, value):
        value_list = value.split(' ')
        search_vector = SearchVector(name)
        query_list = [SearchQuery(value) for value in value_list]
        while len(query_list) > 1:
            query1 = query_list.pop()
            query2 = query_list.pop()
            query_list.append(query1 & query2)
        search_query = query_list[0]
        return queryset.annotate(search=search_vector).filter(search=search_query)
```

Он может искать по отдельным словам в названиях

Например запрос: localhost/api/addresses/?name=the cafe

Выдает объекты с названиями:
The Buddy cafe, Cafe Imperial, Corner Cafe и прочие похожие.

Данное поведение меня устраивает, но хотелось бы большего, чтобы я мог допустить ошибку или забыл переключить раскладку, например:

?name=the cfe

?name=еру сфау

Есть ли либы, которые помогли бы реализовать такую фичу?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем, раскладку мне переключать не нужно было по ТЗ

А по поиску с ошибками нашел очень интересный вариант TrigramExtension

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/postgres/operations/#trigramextension

Ищет вполне сносно. Интересно устанавливается через добавление django.contrib.postgres в INSTALLED_APPS и через миграции

```
from django.contrib.postgres.operations import TrigramExtension, UnaccentExtension
from django.db import migrations


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    operations = [
        TrigramExtension(),
    ]
```

И реализуется в одну строчку

```
def filter_name_smart(self, queryset, name, value):
    return queryset.filter(name__trigram_similar=value)
```

Или даже без метода

```
class AddressFilter(filters.FilterSet):
    name = filters.CharFilter(lookup_expr='trigram_similar')
```